# unused argument (.encoding = "UTF-8")

Tags: r, tm

I perform analysis of twitter's message (the code for authorization is absent).
Here the code

```
generateCorpus <- function(df, my.stopwords = c()) {
            tw.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))
            tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus, removePunctuation)
            tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus, tolower)
            tw.corpus <- tm_map(tw.corpus, removeWords, my.stopwords)
            tw.corpus
          }

 wordcloud.generate=function(corpus,min.freq=3){
  doc.m = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
  dm = as.matrix(doc.m)
  # calculate the frequency of words
  v = sort(rowSums(dm), decreasing=TRUE)
  d = data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
  #Generate the wordcloud
  wc=wordcloud(d$word, d$freq, min.freq=min.freq)
  wc
}
tweets.grabber=function(searchTerm,num=200){
  rdmTweets = searchTwitter(searchTerm, n=num,.encoding='UTF-8')
  tw.df=twListToDF(rdmTweets)
  tweets <- as.vector(sapply(tw.df$text, RemoveAtPeople))
  as.vector(sapply(tweets,RemoveHTTP))
}

tweets=tweets.grabber('man',num=200)
```

after that expression i get this error

```
 Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) : 
  unused argument (.encoding = "UTF-8")
```

what's wrong? How  eliminate this error?
Thank you